# Is there any API in Survey Monkey which recycles an existing collector to new email IDs?

Tags: rest, api, surveymonkey

We have two APIs on their documentation page which are used to send emails to target recipients. They are:

- https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/methods/create_flow/
- https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/methods/send_flow/

However none of them reuses an already existing collector to just send mail to new recipients. Is there any API which can be used only to send the mails rather than recreating a collector?

Is it mandatory to send a new collector everytime we send new surveys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two links you document are for old V2 APIs which are being deprecated. The new API docs are [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/).

Particularly, you are looking for these:

- https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages
- https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-send

Example:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages
{
    "type": "invite"
}
```

To create a new message (add optional subject/email body) then:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id>/send
{}
```

With an empty body and it'll schedule your email to send (you can also set a date to schedule the email to send at that time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding me to v3, I was getting puzzled with half deprecated v2.